# How to get product's details using order id in Magento 2 admin grid?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, orders, grid

In my Custom Module Magento 2 I want to get Ordered product info by using order id using the Admin grid.

Currently, I get the order id but I want the details of the ordered product also how did I fetch that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    namespace Stackoverflow\OrderedProduct\Block;

    class OrderItems extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {

       protected $_productloader;  
      
       protected $orderRepository;  


      public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
            \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository

        ) {
            $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
            $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }
        public function getLoadProduct($id)
        {
            return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
        }
        
        public functino getorderedProduct()
        {
            $orderId = '12'; 
            $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
            
            $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
            
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $productId = $item->getProductId();
                $product = $this->getLoadProduct($productId);
                if($product->getSku()){
                  print_r($product->getData());
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

For admin grid i consider you have created grid using Ui_Compoonent. So consider the column definition as below

```
<column name="order_id" class="Stackoverflow\OrderedProduct\Ui\Component\Column\Product">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="boolean">text</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>                  
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Create Product.php under Stackoverflow\OrderedProduct\Ui\Component\Column  and add below code

```
<?php


namespace Stackoverflow\OrderedProduct\Ui\Component\Column;



use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;


class Product extends Column {

    protected $_productloader;  

    protected $orderRepository;  

    public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context, 
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    array $components = [], 
    array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

   
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {

        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                if (isset($item['id_field_name']) && isset($item['order_id'])) {
                    $orderId =  $item['order_id'];
                    $orderedProduct = $this->getorderedProduct($orderId);
                    if(!empty[$orderedProduct]){
                         $item = implode(",", $orderedProduct);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      $item = 'N/A';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
    
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }
    
    public functino getorderedProduct($orderId)
        {
            $productSku = []
            $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);

            $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $productId = $item->getProductId();
                /*
                 Just to get sku you can use this code.
                 $productSku = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
                    
                */
                
                $product = $this->getLoadProduct($productId);
                if($sku = $product->getSku()){
                 $productSku = $sku;
                }
            }
            
            return $productSku;
        }
}
```

Comment: It is well worked for menu or Frontend how do i show these data using admin grid @Amitkumar

Comment: check my updated answer